# What is the reason for useState() react hooks always returns the initial state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am making a form in react with validation. I have to show the error after validation. So I used `useState()` hook as follows. But it seems i can't update the new state as it always returns the initial value. Where did I go wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';

const Firstname = ({ handleInputChange, firstName }) => {

    const [error, setError] = useState('hi');

    const handleBlur = (event) => {
        const { value } = event.target;
        validateFirstName(value);
    }

    const validateFirstName = (name) => {
        if (name.trim().length === 0) {
            setError('Enter first Name');
        }
        console.log(error);
    }

    return (

        <>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type='text'
                placeholder='Eddard'
                name='firstName'
                value={firstName}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur} />


        </>

    )
}

export default Firstname;
```

I tried to `console.log(error)` but it always returns the `initial state` `hi`.

Comment: setError is async action so console.log would not show the real value. BTW `name.trim().length === 0` this mean that the input is empty

Comment: Think about the control flow. How can the line where error is assigned to possibly be reached between you calling setError and the console.log?

Comment: try adding something like `<button onClick={()=>console.log(error)}>log error</button>` then you can click it to view the state without the complexities of setState being async

Answer (score 1):

This is because state updates are asynchronous.
You need to `console.log(error)` just before your `return` to see it at each render.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was doing ```console.log(error)```inside the function all the time, so it didn't render at that time. I tried outside the function and worked.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the input, you should use `defaultValue` instead of `value`

```
<input type='text'
    placeholder='Eddard'
    name='firstName'
    defaultValue={firstName}
    onChange={handleInputChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur} />
```

It would also be better if you move the log inside the if-statement

```
const validateFirstName = (name) => {
    if (name.trim().length === 0) {
        setError('Enter first Name');
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous, if you need to catch the new value you can use useEffect.